# SQL Alchemy results to Excel conversion in my Flask project

Tags: python, flask, flask-sqlalchemy

I am a Python novice. I am writing a simple Flask app. I am running into a problem when I try to generate a Excel report from a SQL Alchemy query result. The error I get is:

> TypeError: Value must be a list, tuple, range or generator, or a dict. Supplied value is <class 'dict_keys'>

Can you please help? Thanks

```py
from openpyxl import Workbook
from flask import Response
from app.models import DataModelTbl #inherits from DB.Model

wb = Workbook()
ws = wb.active

# this returns the Flask SQLAlchemy database results
ResultSet = DataModelTbl.query.all()

rows = [u.__dict__ for u in ResultSet]

# Add headers to the Excel sheet
headers = rows[0].keys()

# I get the error here -> 
# TypeError: Value must be a list, tuple, range or generator, or a dict. 
# Supplied value is <class 'dict_keys'>
ws.append(headers)  

# Add data to the Excel sheet
for row_data in rows:
    ws.append(list(row_data.values()))

# Create a response object for the Excel file
open_xml = 'application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet'
response = Response(content_type=open_xml)
response.headers['Content-Disposition'] = 'attachment; filename=data.xlsx'

# Save the Excel workbook to the response
wb.save(response)

return response
```

Answer (score 0):

Dictionary's [`keys()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#dict.keys) method does indeed return `dict_keys` object, which is not a list, but can easily be cast to it with `list(rows[0].keys())`.

Still it may not solve the problem, because the selected object have extra attributes, that could not be written into the worksheet.

To get the columns only and their values, it is possible to [inspect](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/20/core/inspection.html#sqlalchemy.inspect) the model and work with the result [`Mapper`](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/20/orm/mapping_api.html#sqlalchemy.orm.Mapper) object.

```py
from sqlalchemy import inspect

mapper = inspect(DataModelTbl)

headers = [column.name for column in mapper.columns]
ws.append(headers)

for record in ResultSet:
    ws.append([getattr(record, key) for key in headers])
```

There still may be some problems, if you have column types, that cannot be converted to Excel.